# Oracle: elegant way to parse a number to 9,99 format

Tags: oracle, numbers, format

With Oracle 11g I want to parse a number to strip decimals if their value is 0 and keep two decimal figure after the decimal separator ',' if the value of decimals is different from 0

Example:

```
1,00 -> 1
1,001 -> 1
0,203 -> 0,20
```

And so on.

I've obtained something like that in a very unelegant way

```
select replace(trim(to_char (trunc ('0,2345',2),'9999999990.99')), '.', ',')
from dual
```

Do you know more elegant way? The output should be a char (not number).

Comment: Why do you need to get incorrect answers, as you mentonied in comments for AlexPoole answer? I mean that 112,999 must be 113 if you round that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's much more elegant, but assuming your replace is to deal with different locales, this might work for you:

```
with t as (
  select 1.00 as n from dual
  union all select 1.001 from dual
  union all select 0.203 from dual
  union all select 0.2345 from dual
  union all select 112.999 from dual
)
select n, regexp_replace(to_char(trunc(n, 2), '9999999990D00',
  'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''), '[,.]00$', null) as new_n
from t;

         N NEW_N        
---------- --------------
         1           1    
     1.001           1    
     0.203           0,20 
    0.2345           0,23 
   112.999         112,99
```

The `nls_param` argument to [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions201.htm) let's you dictate whether it used a comma or a period as the decimal separator. If you can set that at session level then the query looks a bit simpler. The `regexp_replace` strips `,00` (or `.00`, which come to think of it is overkill) from the end of th string.

---

As ThinkJet noted the `regexp_replace` is a bit excessive, and since the decimal seperator is defined in the column clase (and the format has no group separators anyway) it can be done with a plan `replace`:

```
with t as (
  select 1.00 as n from dual
  union all select 1.001 from dual
  union all select 0.203 from dual
  union all select 0.2345 from dual
  union all select 112.999 from dual
  union all select 13.08 from dual
)
select n, replace(trim(
    to_char(trunc(n, 2), '9999999990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')),
    ',00', null) as new_n
from t;

         N NEW_N        
---------- --------------
         1 1              
     1.001 1              
     0.203 0,20           
    0.2345 0,23           
   112.999 112,99         
     13.08 13,08
```

Still not sure this can be described as 'elegant' though.

Comment: @Sam - I missed the trunc. I've added that and updated the answer to show the result for that value.

Comment: @AlexPoole With `trunc()` results wrong again, just try something like `1.308`. Must be `round() here`. Also, from my point of view using regular expression for such a thing is like using steam-hummer to crack nuts.

Comment: @ThinkJet - agree your decode is neater, although it evaluates trunc/round twice. But the OP specifically wants 12,99 and 13,08. I initially was letting it round naturally and added trunc on request. Have to assume the OP has that requirement for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I ask OP about that requirement. It's looking strange for me.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve correct results you must deal with numbers, not strings:

```
with t as (
  select 1.00 as n from dual
  union all select 1.001 from dual
  union all select 0.203 from dual
  union all select 0.2345 from dual
  union all select 112.999 from dual
  union all select 112.105 from dual
  union all select 0 from dual
  union all select -12.307 from dual
)
select
  n,
  decode( trunc(n,2) - trunc(n) , 
    0, to_char(trunc(n), 'TM9', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', '''),
    to_char(trunc(n,2),'9999999990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', ''')
  ) 
    string_val  
from t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14487)

P.S. Updated to get incorrect truncation instead of round, as in OP request.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant

```
SELECT n,
      to_char( trunc( n, 2 ), 
               case when mod( trunc( n, 2 ), 1 ) = 0
                    then '9990' 
                    else '9990D00'
               end, 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''' ) val
from t
;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69d27/25)

Comment: Ok, good variant. Just make format parameter longer [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a308b/1)